# Como agregar seguridad XSS (Cross Site Scripting) a mi proyecto PHP

Tags: php, php8, scripting, xss

Actualmente estoy en el proceso de publicación de un aplicativo de encuestas, sin embargo quiero agregar seguridad XSS (Cross Site Scripting) para evitar cualquier ataque

En mi caso se podría dar el ataque en las sesiones, por ejemplo mi archivo **validacion.php**

les comparto el código del mismo

```
<?php   

session_start();

$id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
echo $id_usuario;
$clave  = $_POST['clave'];
echo $clave;
include("conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM sistema_encuestasv1.usuarios WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND clave = '$clave'";
   
   $resultado = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
   
   
   if ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)) {


       if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '1') {
           $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
           $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
           header("Location: administrador/index.php");
       } else {
           $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
           $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
           header("Location: usuario/index.php");
       }
       
       if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '3') {
           $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
           $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
           header("Location: usuario_vista/index.php");
       }

   } else {
       header("Location: index.php");
   }

   if (!$query) {
       printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
       exit();
   }


?>
```

Si alguien me puede indicar como se podría agregar esta seguridad, se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: El tema de la seguridad es muy amplio, y cada contexto tiene su propia forma de aplicarla. Para comprender cómo aplicar **seguridad en tu sesión** [lee aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.security.php). Hay otros aspectos en los que tu código **es inseguro**, por ejemplo, es vulnerable a **ataques de inyección SQL**. Ese aspecto no se resuelve dando seguridad a tu sesión, sino aplicando consultas preparadas. Si para cada caso no usas la herramienta adecuada, te harás la ilusión de que el código es seguro, pero no lo es en realidad.

Comment: Y como podria agregar **tokens CSRF** a mi validacion

Comment: Imagina que pasaría si en el `input` de la clave un usuario malintencionado pusiera `1234 or 1 = 1` como quedaría tu `string` de sentencia? Revisa [esta](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) documentación para mejorar los llamados a instrucciones SQL. Luego avanzas con `tokens` y validaciones para XSS.